# Tomcat 8.5.23 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start

Tags: eclipse, maven, java-web-start, jnlp, tomcat8.5

I'm trying to run an embedded tomcat application via java web start. 
The Application runs fine on eclipse but causes problems when launched as a web start file. 
This is the error I am facing now. 
Im using eclipse photon with maven and Tomcat 8.5.23

Kindly do help me out!

This is my error log...

```
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
at 
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:948)
at     
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal
(StandardEngine.java:262)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at   
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal
(StandardService.java:422)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at 
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal
(StandardServer.java:793)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:367)
at com.NO.JO.App.main(App.java:24)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.executeApplication(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.executeMainClass(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.doLaunchApp(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

this is my code...

```
package com.NO.JO;

import java.io.File;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException;
import org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat;

public class App {

public static void main(String[] args) throws LifecycleException, 
InterruptedException, 
                                 ServletException {
String docBase = "src/main/webapp/";

Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();
String webPort = System.getenv("PORT");
    if(webPort == null || webPort.isEmpty()) {
        webPort = "8189";
    }
    tomcat.setPort(Integer.valueOf(webPort));

tomcat.addWebapp("/", new File(docBase).getAbsolutePath());
System.out.println("configuring app with basedir: " + new File("./" + 
docBase).getAbsolutePath());

tomcat.start();
tomcat.getServer().await();
}
}
```

And this is my pom.xml file...

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.NO</groupId>
<artifactId>JO</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>embeddedTomcatSample Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<properties>
<tomcat.version>8.5.23</tomcat.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
<dependency>
<groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
<artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
<version>3.0.1</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
    <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-jasper</artifactId>
    <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-jasper-el</artifactId>
    <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-jsp-api</artifactId>
    <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
<finalName>embeddedTomcatSample</finalName>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>appassembler-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
        <configuration>
            <assembleDirectory>target</assembleDirectory>
            <programs>
                <program>
                    <mainClass>launch.Main</mainClass>
                    <name>webapp</name>
                </program>
            </programs>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>assemble</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Changed my tomcat version to the latest that is 9.0.10
Changed all the dependencies to the above version as well. This fixed the issue.
Give it a try.

Comment: Unfortunately  with 9.0.10 the server doesn't start, it stops  at a secure random warning. So i had to trace back to the tomcat 8 series and am facing the same issue again.